# How can I make sure that plots are not cutoff when saving as a jpeg in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, jpeg

I have created a combined plot with `ggarrange` which looks good in the plot window, however when I save it as a jpeg at 300dpi A4 size I notice that the legend of plot A and the boxplot titles for plot B get cut off, as if they are not being resized appropriately for the size I specified. I've also noticed that the size of the font in the legend is larger than what it looks on R prior to saving.

Saved image as jpeg
[image: Saved image as jpeg]

Screenshot from R studio
[image: Screenshot from R studio]

These are the codes for my plots:

Plot A

```
taxaplot2 <- ggplot(group, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Species)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = Species2, values = Cb64k) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", text=element_text(size=11),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=0, vjust=1)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol=5)) +
  facet_grid(cols=vars(group), scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  ggtitle(opt$gtitle) +
  xlab("Patient ID") + ylab("Relative Abundance")
```

Plot B

```
pl <- ggplot(df.humann2.sub.all4, aes(x=as.factor(PEDIS), y=PathAbundance, fill=as.factor(PEDIS)))
pl <- pl + geom_boxplot()
pl <- pl + facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

Combining plots and export

```
combined_plot <- ggarrange(taxachart2, pl, heights = c(4,1.75), labels=c("A","B"), ncol=1, nrow=2)

jpeg("test2.jpeg", units = "in", width = 8, height = 11, res=300)
combined_plot
dev.off()
```

How can I ensure that the saved image will look exactly the same as the screenshot above?

Comment: There's not a good workflow for that (not that I know of). Font sizes are specified in `pt`, which is a physical length--72pt = 1 inch. When you export with `jpeg` and specify, say, 10 pt font and a resolution of 300 dots per inch, you are implicitly saying that you want the font to be ~42 pixels tall. Generally, you should save a version, open the file, and adjust the code, save again, etc.--which can be quite tedious. Use an image viewer that will auto-update when the file is modified to improve the process by not needed to close  and re-open the file every time.

Comment: The other option is to use RStudio's export button, located at the top of the Plots window. This gives you a plot window that you can resize manually and then save. It displays the dimensions, so you can reproduce the plot programmatically by using those same dimensions in code.